# Select box fails to fetch option value with white spaces after POST

Tags: php, html

I have a select box which fetches the values from the database.the options in the database are:

1. Newyork city
2. Jeju island

the select box shows the exact values from the database.
I have a submit button which POSTs the values to another page.
My problem is when I echo the selected option value the words after the white spaces are not shown i.e it shows only 'Newyork'.
Here is my code:

```
   <select name="users_desc" id="hometexts">
   <option selected='selected' value='' disabled='disabled'  >Select Name</option>";
    <?php 
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT public_desc,public_id FROM table");
                     while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
                    { 
                          if ($_GET['users_desc']==$row["public_id"]) 
                        {
                           echo '<option selected="selected" value='.$row["public_desc"].'>'.$row["public_desc"].'</option>';
                        } 
                        else 
                        {
                           echo '<option value='.$row["public_desc"].'>'.$row["public_desc"].'</option>';
                        }

                    }
                    ?>
                    </select>
```

code for POSTing the option value to another page.

```
if(isset($_POST['login_btn']))
{
    $desc=$_POST['users_desc'];

    echo $desc;
    header("location:publicUserReports.php");

}
```

I just want to get the complete value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to quote the values

```
value="'.$row["public_desc"].'"
```

So

```
echo '<option selected="selected" value="'.$row["public_desc"].'">'.$row["public_desc"].'</option>';
```

When you look at the HTML it must show

```
<option value="Jeju island">
```

instead of

```
<option value=Jeju island>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for more information, there is a great difference between " and '
if you are going to out a string/text with no variables to concatenate you should always use single quote (').

But if you have some variables to concatenate, you should use(optional) the double quote ("). Personally i preferred using it because it is more readable.

Examples:

if im just going to output, lets say: i love coding. then i use:

```
echo 'I love Coding';
```

but when i have some variables to concatenate, i use:

```
echo "I $action Coding";
```

now based on your problem:

```
echo "<option selected='selected' value='$row[public_desc]'>$row[public_desc]</option>";
```

for me this is more readable and less prone to error :)

Comment: Except it will tempt you to do so everywhere and when you get to write JSON you will get a surprise ;)